# Manual close event on delegated jQuery UI tooltip

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Trying to manually close tooltip using link in tooltip, however, since it's a delegated tooltip, I'm unable to achieve this.

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YhV5B/

```
$('#ui-tooltip-0').delegate('.tooltip-close', 'click', function(e) {
    alert("yes");
    var $this = $(e.target);
    $(this).tooltip('close');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should track the event target:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e){
        var myTarget = e.target;
        if( $(myTarget).attr('class') === 'tooltip-close' ){
            $('.tooltip-open').tooltip('close');
        }        
    });
```

I have updated the code on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YhV5B/1/)

Comment: Thanks Mukesh. That worked beautifully.Much appreciated!